# What does the "qui" mean in "crabes pressés qui disparaissent"?

Tags: grammaire, subordonnées, pronoms-relatifs

I'm reading a novel titled "*Attention aux pickpockets*". Here is a paragraph describing a young man drawing on a bulletin board in a train station:

> Oubliant ses problèmes, son renvoi et les yeux tristes de son père, le jeune garçon s'attaqua au panneau. C'est fou comme le métro ressemble à la mer… Le béton des quais, c'est la plage, les trains passent les uns après les autres, comme des vagues, des voyageurs montent ou descendent, petits crabes pressés qui disparaissent. Il y fait chaud et un soleil artificiel ne laisse jamais place à la nuit.  […]

I fancy "*crabes pressés qui disparaissent*" means "crabs hurrying up and leaving"… but how to understand the "*qui*" here?

I know "*qui*" normally means "who" in English, it's used to glue up the main sentence and its clause. But grammar-wise, what does this "*qui*" serve here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The meaning of *qui* is *who*. I'd translate that frament as *hurrying crabs who are leaving* or *squeezed crabs who are leaving*. I think the ambiguity about the several meaning of *pressé* is voluntary here.